# Calling a Powershell function from Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, function, windows-task-scheduler

Powershell 7:

I have a function in my $PSModulePath.  From the PS console, this works fine:

```
Invoke-Main -Env DEV -Exchange AU -Period DAILY
```

In Windows Task Scheduler I've configured:

```
Program Script:  "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe"
Add Arguments:  Invoke-Main -Env DEV -Exchange AU -Period DAILY, and
Add Arguments:  -Command {Invoke-Main -Env DEV -Exchange AU -Period DAILY}
```

These do nothing although Task Scheduler returns 0x0

I put this in a .ps1 file:

```
Invoke-Main -Env DEV -Exchange ALL -Period DAILY, and
& Invoke-Main -Env DEV -Exchange ALL -Period DAILY
```

and

```
AddArguments: path-to.ps1, and
AddArguments: -File path-to.ps1
```

Both work fine from the PS console, but both hang in Task Scheduler with 0x41301.

I've got other PS scripts running from Task Scheduler fine, so I know how to do that.  In fact they contain the code that is in Invoke-Main.  It just started becoming a maintenance hassle so I moved the code to a function.

I'm out of ideas how to get Task Scheduler to invoke a PS function.

Comment: You need to start the task scheduler with a User Account.  The user account will have the PSMOdulePath defined.  The default account the task scheduler uses is a System Account with no environment so PSModule Path is not defined.

Comment: I assume you mean start the scheduled *task* with a User Account, since the Task *Scheduler* runs as a service under the Local System account.  Yes, the scheduled task is running under a user account.  The configured user is my user account, i.e. the one I log on with.  I have tried "only when user is logged on" and "whether user is logged on or not".  I've run a simple test.ps1 with the line "$env:PSModulePath" | Out-File $logfile -Force -Append, and $PSModulePath is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I did Google and searched SO before my initial post.  However, sometimes you just don't use the right search string.

Today after further Googling I found this:

[Use Scheduled Tasks to Run PowerShell Commands on Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-scheduled-tasks-to-run-powershell-commands-on-windows/)

The "secret" was using the ampersand with the -Command switch.  So the final Task Scheduler command string is:

```
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -Command &{Invoke-Main -Env DEV -Exchange AU -Period DAILY}
```

Also useful for debugging is adding the -NoExit switch to the pwsh.exe command until the process is completely debugged.

Hope this helps if someone finds this question in the future.

Comment: Cmdlet like Invoke-Main have to be at the beginning of command (or just after a pipe).  Adding the ampersand and curly brackets creates a child process so that Invoke-Main is the beginning of a command so you do not get any errors.